# Manifolds are locally Euclidean, is the vector space structure of $\mathbb R^n$ important for the definition?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

A manifold $M$ is second countable, Hausdorff, locally Euclidean space. Locally Euclidean means that for every point $p \in M$ there is a homeomorphism $\phi$ from a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ to an open set of $\mathbb R^n$.

My question is: do we care about the *vector space structure* of $\mathbb R^n$ in the definition or even about the Euclidean inner product on it ? If not, then all we need is the topology induced by the inner product on the *set* $\mathbb R^n$. Is that correct ? Because otherwise the addition and scaling of vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ doesn't mean any thing on the manifold by the inverse of the coordinate map $\phi^{-1}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct. The vector space structure and the inner product have no significance. The only structure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is of relevance is the topology. In particular, it is the only structure that the map $\phi$ is required to be compatible with.

Comment: +1, though if the manifold is smooth (as per the tags), we need derivatives, which do use the vector space structure.

Comment: I have a very different question if I may, it is about smooth structures on manifolds. Does a smooth structure on a manifold provides a criterion for jodging smoothness of functions on the manifolds like a topology providing a criterion for continuity of functions on a its space ? or should I make this a seperate question ?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: That's a good point, though I was interpreting their question as one seeking to clarify the locally Euclidean condition (as evidenced by the title).

Comment: @Physor: Yes it does. Just as continuity only makes sense for maps between spaces equipped with topologies, smoothness only makes sense for maps between manifolds equipped with smooth structures

Comment: So the same function on the same manifold can be smooth wrt some coordinate map (and all its compatible ones) and not smooth wrt to another coordinate map (from a different maximal atlas), right ? I can't find an example right now

Comment: @Physor: Correct.

Comment: Just to add a bit more to the answer by @MichaelAlbanese. As a curiosity, there are generalizations to the notion of "topological/smooth manifold", in which the idea of the transition maps being homeomorphisms or diffeomorphisms, they are required to belong to a certain "pseudogroup of transformations". In the pseudogroup of diffeomorphisms, we require the transition maps to be smooth (which needs in some way the vector structure of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$) but in other pseudogroups it is not necessary to consider that structure.